# Orange does not show Geo Map tool on OS X

Tags: orange, geospatial

I am using Orange 3.3.11 and I cannot find "Geo Map" widget on OS X.

But the [documentation](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/visualize/geomap.html) says there is such a widget. How can I find this widget?

Comment: Might appear in the upcoming release. The file _is_ present in the source code repository. You might try installing the development version. https://github.com/biolab/orange3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if you have the widget "Map" in your Visualization group. It might be the same widget, just with the different name.

It looks "Geo Map" widget appears for Orange 3.4.2 for Linux, in Visualize group:

[image]

However, from this [commit](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/search?q=geo%20map&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93) in Orange source code, it looks the previous name for this widget was just "Map".